# What are the events that cause Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED to be broadcasted?

Tags: android, android-intent

### Background

I have an [**app-manager**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager) alternative app that needs to monitor certain app changes of the OS.

The reason for this is to know when to update the information of the list of apps.

One of the events that my app listens to is Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED .

### The problem

[**Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED documentation**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED) says something that is too general:

> Broadcast Action: An existing application package has been changed
>   (e.g. a component has been enabled or disabled). The data contains the
>   name of the package.

They give only a single example of when it's called (app got enabled/disabled), but according to what I've seen, this is actually the only event that causes it.

### The question

What other events (other than app being disabled/enabled) cause this intent to be fired?

Also, I don't get this part of the documentation:

> EXTRA_DONT_KILL_APP containing boolean field to override the default
>   action of restarting the application.

What does it mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I think enabling\disabling application components like Receivers will also fire this intent:

```
boolean batteryLow = intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW);

PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
ComponentName passiveLocationReceiver = new ComponentName(context, PassiveLocationChangedReceiver.class);

// Disable the passive location update receiver when the battery state is low.
// Disabling the Receiver will prevent the app from initiating the background
// downloads of nearby locations.
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(passiveLocationReceiver,
  batteryLow ? PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED : PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DEFAULT,
  PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Take a look on the sources
https://code.google.com/p/android-protips-location/source/browse/trunk/src/com/radioactiveyak/location_best_practices/

And look through the corresponding article
http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html

Comment: I asked if there are also other cases that it gets fired, and not just enable/disable which is what is written in the documentation. I also asked about "EXTRA_DONT_KILL_APP" .

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.